# Symfony2 Choices from Entity Field

Tags: symfony

I have an entity ChoiceQuestion which has a field Options.
Options is defined as an Array.

```
<?php

namespace Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity;

use Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\BaseQuestion;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @author GKLESSE
 *
 */
class RadioQuestion extends BaseQuestion {
    const TYPE = 'radio';
    /**
    /* @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    protected $options;
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $questionOrder;

    /**
     * @var \Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey
     */
    protected $survey;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->questiontype = self::TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * Set options
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return RadioQuestion
     */
    public function setOptions($options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param string $question
     * @return RadioQuestion
     */
    public function setQuestion($question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Set questionOrder
     *
     * @param integer $questionOrder
     * @return RadioQuestion
     */
    public function setQuestionOrder($questionOrder)
    {
        $this->questionOrder = $questionOrder;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get questionOrder
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQuestionOrder()
    {
        return $this->questionOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Set survey
     *
     * @param \Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey $survey
     * @return RadioQuestion
     */
    public function setSurvey(\Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey $survey = null)
    {
        $this->survey = $survey;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get survey
     *
     * @return \Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey 
     */
    public function getSurvey()
    {
        return $this->survey;
    }
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $questiontype;


    /**
     * Set questiontype
     *
     * @param string $questiontype
     * @return RadioQuestion
     */
    public function setQuestiontype($questiontype)
    {
        $this->questiontype = $questiontype;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get questiontype
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getQuestiontype()
    {
        return $this->questiontype;
    }
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    protected $answers;


    /**
     * Add answers
     *
     * @param \Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Answer $answers
     * @return RadioQuestion
     */
    public function addAnswer(\Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Answer $answers)
    {
        $answers->setQuestion($this);
        $this->answers[] = $answers;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove answers
     *
     * @param \Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Answer $answers
     */
    public function removeAnswer(\Survey\SurveyBundle\Entity\Answer $answers)
    {
        $this->answers->removeElement($answers);
    }

    /**
     * Get answers
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAnswers()
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }
}
```

In Symfony2 I want to create a form and as part of that form display the Options from that entity as "choices".

I implemented the following:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder();
$form->add($question->getQuestionOrder(), 'choice',array('label' => $question->getQuestion(), 'choices' => $question->getOptions()));
$formbuilder->add($question->getId(), 'checkbox',array('label' => $question->getQuestion(), 'choices' => $question->getOptions()));
```

However when checking the page I get the following error which makes no sense to me:

```
The option "choices" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name" ...
```

How come Symfony2 tells me that choices does not exist since it is obviously part of the form setup?

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: That looks right to me.  Have you got any other similar forms working?

Comment: I found it, despite it's name you don't use the type Checkbox for a multiple select form type.

You need to use choice with option Multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

Instead of using the form type "checkbox" to render multiple selects, you need to use "choice" with the options:

```
"multiple" => true, "expanded" => true
```

Comment: Bit confused by this, the example in your question uses the `choice` type, not `checkbox`?

Comment: And that's my fault, I didn't submit the entire code (which I will do in the future).

I had another field below the choice field of type Checkbox and added the Choices there as well (thinking it would result in multiple checkboxes).

Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Aha!  Not to worry, glad you got it working.  Might be an idea to edit your original question, at the moment it doesn't make much sense along with the eventual answer, so it won't be any help to someone with a similar problem.